# Cannot add/subtract from large doubles in Objective C

Tags: objective-c, double

I am trying to subtract 1 from a double with this code:

```
-(NSMutableArray *)getMoreTwitterDataWithMaxID:(double)maxID {
    double newestID = (maxID - 1);
    NSLog(@"newest ID is %f and maxID is %f", newestID, maxID);
    // other code
}
```

The console is spitting this out:

```
2012-05-15 11:21:14.693 nearYou[2570:3a03] newest ID is 202429657738522624.000000 and maxID is 202429657738522624.000000
```

I'm not sure why they aren't subtracting . . .

Any help greatly appreciated!

Comment: How many bits of precision does a `double` have?  How many bits are needed to represent 202429657738522625 in binary?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may have reached the limits of the double floating point format. The 64-bit floating point format only has a 52-bit mantissa, meaning it can only hold an integer of 52 bits with any integer accuracy before it uses the exponent.  Your number is larger than that so the gap between one integer and the next possible one has grown bigger than 1.

Comment: Yep, except delete "may" and replace 52 with 53.

Comment: Thanks for the info thats very helpful. Should I use a float then instead?

Comment: Nope: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format.  52-bit mantissa, 11-bit exponent and 1 bit sign.

Comment: No don't use a float, that's even worse as that has a smaller mantissa.  Use a 64-bit integer.

Comment: @Cthutu: 52 *explicit* bits.  1 *implicit* bit.  53 significand bits in all.

Comment: Are you including the sign bit when you count 53?

Comment: thanks guys. I used the NSDecimalNumber instead and it works fine. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @SeanDanzeiser try int instead. Less memory, easier.

Comment: @Cthutu: no, that doesn't include the sign bit.  All normal numbers (which include all integral values) have a significand of the form `1.xxx...xxx`.  The 52 `x`s are the explicit portion of the significand, the leading `1` is the implicit bit (which isn't actually stored anywhere).

Comment: Right, I understand - you weren't referring to the size of the mantissa, you were referring to the other 52 that referred to the size of the integer that can be represented with accuracy.

Answer (score 4):

May be you have reached the limit of the double data type. You can use [NSDecimal](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDecimalNumber_Class/Reference/Reference.html) instead.

Comment: If a 64-bit integer is not enough, then you can use NSDecimal.  But if you're using only integers and 64-bits is enough then NSDecimal is overkill.